# discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'qualified_name'

Tags: python, discord.py, command, bots, nonetype

I am making a custom help command for my bot and here is my code.

```py
class customhelpcommand(commands.HelpCommand):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
    
    async def send_bot_help(self, mapping):
        for cog in mapping:
            await self.get_destination().send(f"{cog.qualified_name}: {[command.name for command in mapping(cog)]}")
     

    async def send_cog_help(self, cog):
        await self.get_destination().send(f"{cog.qualified_name}: {[command.name for command in cog.get_commands()]}")
```

Comment: it gives the error :
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'qualified_name'

Comment: you first check the object (e.g. if cog is not None: ...)  then you should move further.

Answer (score 3):

Some cogs in your `mapping` might be `None`. Therefore you can simply check it:

```py
async def send_bot_help(self, mapping):
    for cog in mapping:
        if cog is not None:
            await self.get_destination().send(f"{cog.qualified_name}: {[command.name for command in mapping(cog)]}")
```